# Foundation 6 CSS not working

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

i just installed Foundation 6 through:

```
foundation new
```

I chose Foundation for Sites. The file structure is created ann all look ok.

then i run

```
foundation watch
```

everything looks fine. The gulp runs and watches the changes.

i then created _custom.scss and imported it into app.scss with:

```
@import 'custom';
```

i even put the command to the end of the file to see if this changes anything.

I write some css in the custom file then i save.

I can see the custom css created inside scss/app.scss file but the custom CSS does not appear.

Also even if i change a parametter in _settings.scss like

```
$body-background: $black;
```

it has no effect.

All the above changes are reflected in the

```
foundation watch
```

terminal window though. I can see the sass compiler updating without errors.
thanks

Comment: Check if there are any errors in your file, If there are any errors, your saved changes wont reflect

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's cache, you should check that. I don't know how `foundation new` is working, but it's watching the foundation source code right? Maybe there is a conflict between **foundation** tool and **gulp**. What I mean by that is that maybe foundations is compiling, then gulp is recompiling without your file.

I suggest you to check:

- Maybe there is some cache provided either by foundation or by gulp-cache or other plugin
- It is possible some kind of rewrite, so check that too
- Make sure there are no errors in your file, otherwise the changes won't be made
- Your custom file should be included last, so it can overwrite other classes

If this didn't help, try a different approach with gulp and bower. Make these changes to your gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    ...,
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

var paths = {
    css: [
        'bower_components/foundation-6/css/foundation.min.css',
        'src/sass/*.scss',
        'src/sass/**/*.scss'
    ],
    ...
}

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root:       'dist',
        livereload: true,
        host:       '0.0.0.0',
        port:       '8080'
    });
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.css)
    .pipe(sass())
    ...
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.css,   ['css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'css', 'watch']);
```

Basically I am suggesting to download foundation scss with bower, and include it in gulp.